# What do I need to go from having a domain to being able to take a sipuser@mydomain.com call?

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, sip

(Sorry if this question is a little basic or should go on a different SE site.  Just let me know.)

I'm trying to learn about SIP. The problem is that I'm at the point where I don't know enough to try it myself to learn and sometimes I don't know enough to know what question to ask. I have seen that you can get a SIP account/username from websites like ekiga.net that will give you something like me@ekiga.net that you can sign into with a client software like Ekiga (the software).

So, what things would I have to set up/do to make it so a can take a domain I have (like azendale.com) and set up an account like me@azendale.com have the SIP calls come in to Ekiga?

I'm not looking for step by step instructions so much, but instead to understand what pieces I need to set up/have in place for this to work.

I currently have an 12.04 server with a public IP (and IPv6 also), so I'm hoping that may sidestep issues I might have with NAT (I've heard that part can be tricky, and would be fine using only IPv6 if that makes it easier).

Answer (score 1):

1. A SIP server to deal with the incoming calls (and indeed [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) is a good open-source choice, and available as ubuntu package).
2. DNS records publishing the right service to use for SIP service. For example to correctly process the SIP url [SIP:eham@idefix.net](http://SIP:eham@idefix.net) I added SRV records to DNS:

`_sip._udp.idefix.net has SRV record 0 0 5060 abaris.idefix.net.`

Not all SIP clients use SRV records (by default).

And most SIP clients do not support IPv6 yet.

(what happens with eham@idefix.net is explained at [metar in asterisk](http://idefix.net/~koos/asterisk/metarinasterisk.html).

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a SIP server like [Astarisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) (though astarisk is a bit more). You set it up and create users. That's what you need.